# Red vid layout for columns

Tags: red

How to align columns nicely:

Things OK for :

```
    view layout [

        title "How to align ?"

        panel [
            text "" text "col1" text "col2"
        ]

        return

        panel [
            text "very short" field "" field ""
        ]
        return
        panel [
            text "short" field "" field ""
        ]

    ]
```

[image]

Things gets wrong with:

```
    view layout [

        title "How to align ?"

        panel [
            text "" text "col1" text "col2"
        ]

        return

        panel [
            text "very short" field "" field ""
        ]
        return
        panel [
            text "short" field "" field ""
        ]
        return
        panel [
            text "but if very very long" field "" field ""
        ]

    ]
```

[image]

Subsequent question: how to narrow space between rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do your panels as columns instead of rows, then you give them specific widths that will serve your needs.

```
view layout  [

    title "How to align ?"

    panel 120x300 [
        text "" return
        text "very short" return
        text "short" return
        text "but if very very long" return

    ]

    panel 120x300 [
        text "col1" return 
        field return
        field return
        field return
    ]

    panel 120x300 [
        text "col2" return 
        field return
        field return
        field return
    ]
]
```

[image]